# How to create custom's User Interface?

Tags: r, shiny

Accidentally i saw this User Interface in a [website](https://alertalicitacao.com.br/), the first thing that i tought was "oh... this is a shiny ui, seems like the developer use `shinydashboard::dashboardHeader()`, `shinydashboard::dashboardBody()` and `shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar()"`, Well but how to do this? I never saw a function to create something similar.. i realize the `actionButton()` but how to do this:

[image]

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
# here

actionButton("button","Faça Login e assine")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
 observeEvent(input$button, {
## do something 
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal `box()` function of shiny along with `hr()` and do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage( 
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
  box(title="TITLE",status="primary",solidHeader=TRUE,style="",
      width=2,
      h1(strong("$89,90")),
      h5("Some text here"),
      hr(),
      h4("More text"),
      hr(),
      h4("More text"),
      hr(),
      h4("More text"),
      hr(),
      h4("More text"),
      hr(),
      actionButton("button","Login and subscribe",class="btn-primary")
  ))
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    ## do something 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This gives an output like :

[image: this]

After this, you can always use css to customize the colors and the fonts in your box.

I hope this answers your question!